Setting up Oracle Connection in ASP.NET Core MVC using C#
I'm so confused how ASP.NET Core MVC works. I need to set up a connection from Oracle database to my project which is in ASP.NET Core. I stored my connection string in appsettings.json, but it ends there. I don't know how to get it from json file and use it in my controller.
I hope someone could point me on the right direction on this.
This is in my appsettings.json:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConn": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXXXXX)(PORT=0000))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test.sample.test)));User Id=USER_TST;Password=UserPass;"
}


A quick search for appsettings.json mvc seems to show some results such as .NET Core MVC - How to Access appsettings.json

Hi If there is this line on Program.cs [builder.Services.AddTransient((sp) =>
new OracleConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn")));], how do I use it on Controller.cs?

The following shows how one can retrieve a database connection string from appsettings.json in a ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) (.NET 8) project.
appSettings.json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DBConnectionStr": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=HOSTSERVER)     (PORT=0001))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TEST.TEST.TEST)));User Id=Test_ID;Password=PassID;"
    }
}


Pre-requisites:
Download/Install NuGet package: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (v8.0.0)

In Solution Explorer, expand <project name>
Right-click <project name> and select Manage NuGet Packages...
Click Browse tab
In the search box, type: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Scroll to the top, and select Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Select desired version (ex: 8.0.0), and click Install
If prompted Visual Studio is about to make changes to this solution. Click OK to proceed with the changes listed below..., click OK

Add using directive:

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


Option 1:
Modify HomeController.cs as shown below:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    //add 'IConfiguration config' to the constructor
    public HomeController(IConfiguration config, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _configuration = config;
        _logger = logger;

        //option1
        string? dbConnectionStr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnectionStr");
        Debug.WriteLine($"HomeController (iconfig): {dbConnectionStr}");

        //option 2
        DBConnectionOptions? options = new DBConnectionOptions();
        options =  _configuration.GetSection(DBConnectionOptions.SectionName).Get<DBConnectionOptions>();
        string? dbConnectionStr2 = options?.DBConnectionStr;
        Debug.WriteLine($"HomeController (options): {dbConnectionStr2}");
    }

    //Additional code/methods here
}



Option 2:
Additional pre-requisites:

Download/Install NuGet package: Microsoft.Extensions.Options (v8.0.2)

Create a class (name: DBConnectionOptions)
public class DBConnectionOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = "ConnectionStrings";

    //name from appsettings.json
    public string? DBConnectionStr { get; set; }
}

In Program.cs, add:
builder.Services.Configure<DBConnectionOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(DBConnectionOptions.SectionName));

Program.cs (full code):
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //added
        builder.Services.Configure<DBConnectionOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(DBConnectionOptions.SectionName));

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }
}

Then in HomeController.cs, add using directive:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
and modify the code as shown below:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly DBConnectionOptions _dbConnectionOptions;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    //add 'IOptions<DBConnectionOptions> dbOptions' to the constructor
    public HomeController(IOptions<DBConnectionOptions> dbOptions, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _dbConnectionOptions = dbOptions.Value;
        _logger = logger;

        Debug.WriteLine($"HomeController (iOptions): {_dbConnectionOptions.DBConnectionStr}");
    }

    //Additional code/methods here

}



Option 3:
In HomeController.cs:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private string? _dbConnStr = string.Empty;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        //create new instance
        Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
        _dbConnStr = configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnectionStr");

        Debug.WriteLine($"_connStr: {_dbConnStr}");
    }
                       
    //Additional code/methods here

}


Resources:

Configuration in ASP.NET Core
.NET Core MVC - How to Access appsettings.json

